# Should I create a new sub-class for any unique object which is the same as base class' object except for the default values?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class:

```
Class Monster 
{
private:
const int force;
const int prize;
const int damage;
}
```

In my code, I want to be able to easily create a unique Monster Object that I call Dragon which has default values for all the Monster's attributes that can't be initialized to different values *(for example: all Dragons has force=5, prize=10, damage=10)*

**My question is- should Dragon be a subclass of Monster even though there is not realy a difference between the two except for the default values and the name of the object?**

(In fact I have many types such as Dragon- each has it's own default values).

It seems that this is going to be a fine solution for my needs but I'm new to OOP and not sure it's acceptable or how to solve it differently, yet elegantly.

Comment: If you have a Dragon, it must be a monster, and if you have a Monster, it doesn't have to be a Dragon. That's the logic that you shouldn't mix the two even there is nothing new about Dragon.

Comment: If you have few classes, that can be enough. But soon enough you will want to add new behaviors and stats and more types of monsters and realize this design doesn't scale at all. Read about the Entity-Component-System & Factory design patterns.

Comment: I personally would design an abstract base-class (interface) for monsters. e.g. MonsterItf.  And then have different classes for monsters with different behavior implementing that interface. If monsters behave the same (e.g. 7 types of dragons with different colors and stats) I would model that as a Dragon class and pass in the properties as arguments to the constructor. And 3 types of wolves as a Wolves class... etc. And then I could still make a list of active monsters by having a list of unique pointers to monster interfaces. e.g. std::list<std::unique_ptr<MonsterItf>> monsters;

Comment: As an alternative to polymorphism, consider an Entity component system architecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system)

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be the cleanest solution, you could create an `enum class` for your different monster types and use a custom method to call the constructor.

```
enum class types {Dragon, Turtle, Squid};

class Monster {
private:
    const int force;
    const int prize;
    const int damage;
public:
    static Monster createMonster(types type) {
        if (type == types::Dragon) {
            return Monster(20, 10, 5);
        }
        else if (type == types::Squid) {
            return Monster(5, 2, 3);
        }
    }
    Monster(int f, int p, int d) : force(f), prize(p), damage(d){};
};


int main(void) {
    Monster dragon1 = Monster::createMonster(types::Dragon);
    Monster squid1 = Monster::createMonster(types::Squid);
    return 0;
}
```